# Python executable does not run : command not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I successfully installed pyinstaller (via conda) and created an executable.
I can see the executable but it does not run

```
'''$ python -V

Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.'''
```

This is on macOS, installed it using

```
'''conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller '''

'''
$ pyinstaller --version

3.4

'''
```

Ran pyinstaller to create an executable

```
pyinstaller --onefile black_box_regression.py
```

I can see the executable successfully created in dist directory

```
$/Users/xyz/dist

$ls -lrt

-rwxr-xr-x  1 xyz  staff  274241591 Jun 17 13:39 black_box_regression
```

but when I run it I get bellow error

```
$ black_box_regression

-bash: black_box_regression: command not found
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have anything to do with Python, it's just standard Unix semantics. You always need to reference an executable via its path:

```
./black_box_regression
```

Comment: That worked, argghh that was basics

Thank you Daniel